# Are there extra flanking rules in Long War 2?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-long-war-2

As far as I've understood the flanking rules in X-Com 2 Long War 2, they're not any different from the flanking rules in X-Com Enemy Unknown or Long War 1. Is there?

Here, an ADVENT soldier is hiding right behind full cover seems to be flanked. How is this happening? The other soldier visible in the picture should be flanking it, but not the one in focus.

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear from the pic if the lamp post provides cover or not. There are a few objects like signs that don't provide any cover at all.

Comment: Right, it was unclear from the screenshot. It was a "cover providing" lamp post, that's where the yellow shield came from. All the surrounding tiles were empty.

Comment: The stance of the enemy sodleir however doesn't indicate, that he is in cover, it looks like, he is standing in the open.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this mod changes anything.

The yellow shield refers to standing next to a half/full cover *in any adjacent direction*. Not necessarily in the direction of your character. In this picture it might be possible that the enemy has a no-cover lamp post between themselves and your character, and behind them, in the background of the picture, a full cover.

The enemy icon above "fire weapon" does however take the cover between the enemy and your character in account, turning yellow when you have the chance of dealing a no cover flanking shot.

Comment: Yes, agreed on everything. Here, the enemy icon is yellow.